# ¿Qué condición puedo crear en Lenguaje C para confirmar mediante una estructura repetitiva que un numero ES PRIMO?

Tags: c

Tengo un ejercicio en el que me piden que halle los primeros 17 numeros primos.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podriamos hacer el trabajo por ti, pero de esa forma nos estarian calificando a nosotros. Tomate el trabajo de intentar hacer algo, y venir cuando te trabes en una parte en especifico. Agrega lo que intentaste hasta el momento

Comment: Piensa cómo lo harías tú mismo sobre el papel. Después intenta expresar tu solución como [pseudocódigo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoc%C3%B3digo). Finalmente traduce a C el pseudocódigo.

Answer (score 1):

Juan Fernando

Yo lo resuelvo de la siguiente manera

incluimos la libreria `conio.h`

incluimos la libreria `stdio.h`

```
 
int main()
{
    int contador, n, primo;
    printf( "\n   " );
```

for ( n = 1 ; n <= 17 ; n++ )
{
    primo = 1;
    contador = 2;

    while ( contador <= n / 2 && primo )
    {
        if ( n % contador == 0 )
            primo = 0;

        contador++;
    }

    if ( primo )
        printf( "%d ", n );
}

getch(); 

return 0; }

Comment: A parte de que algunas personas creen que es mala idea esforzarse en responder una pregunta que el autor no se ha esforzado al redactar, tu código de búsqueda de primos es objetivamente ineficiente (o no tan eficiente como podría ser).

Comment: Bueno, Supuse que el codigo tenia que ser lo mas comprencible para una persona que no tenia ni idea de resolverlo, pero gracias por la observacion. saludos

Comment: La claridad no está reñida con la eficiencia. Podrías en tu bucle incrementar de 2 en 2 empezando en 3 evitando así caclular una enorme cantidad de números que se sabe que no serán primos.